# Symfony 2 set default values on collection field entities

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I've these 2 forms:

Lineups form which edits the lineups field of a match entity

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MatchBundle\Form\Type;

use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository;
use Acme\TeamBundle\Entity\TeamRepository;
use Acme\ApiBundle\Listener\PatchSubscriber;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Form\DataTransformer\TimestampToDateTimeTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class LineupsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('lineups', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => new LineupType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'        => 'Acme\MatchBundle\Entity\Match',
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'match';
    }
}
```

Lineup form which creates/edits a lineup entity

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MatchBundle\Form\Type;

use Acme\PlayerBundle\Entity\PlayerRepository;
use Acme\ApiBundle\Listener\PatchSubscriber;
use Acme\CoreBundle\Form\DataTransformer\TimestampToDateTimeTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class LineupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('player', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmePlayerBundle:Player',
                'property' => 'id',
                'query_builder' => function(PlayerRepository $er) {
                        $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
                        return $query;
                    }
                ))
                ->add('status', 'text')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'        => 'Acme\MatchBundle\Entity\Lineup',
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'match';
    }
}
```

Lineup entity fields

```
/**
 * @var Match $match
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Match", inversedBy="lineups")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $match;

/**
 * @var \Acme\PlayerBundle\Entity\Player $player
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\PlayerBundle\Entity\Player", inversedBy="lineups")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $player;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=16)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $status;
```

Now I've successfully got to add/remove Lineup entities to the lineups field, what I want is to set the $match field of lineup entity to the match edited with the lineups form.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found by myself that binding to the BIND form event let me do what I've needed:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::BIND,
    function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $lineups = $data->getLineups();
        foreach ($lineups as &$lineup) {
            $lineup->setMatch($data);
        }
        $event->setData($data);
    }
);
```

Which works fine ;)

Comment: The lineups array starts with 1 because that is the ID of the first Lineup in your DB.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't needed to do the remove/add thing since I can use the ArrayCollection as reference just editing it.